# Tensorflow creates a new set of already existing variables each session run?

Tags: python, variables, scope, tensorflow, prediction

I'm finally using my LSTM model to predict things. However, I've run into a new problem that I don't quite understand. If I try to predict something using

```
sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: xs})
```

It works great for the first prediction, but any subsequent predictions throw the error:

> ValueError: Variable weight_def/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?

Now, there are a TON of topics on this - and most of them are easily solved by doing what it asks - just create a variable scope around the offending line and make variable reuse true. Now, if I do that I get the following error:

> ValueError: Variable rnn_def/RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

This is causing me quite the headache. I've read the [Tensorflow Variable Sharing](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) documentation over and over, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. Here the offending lines

```
with tf.variable_scope("rnn_def"):
            outputs, states = rnn.rnn(self.__lstm_cell,
                                      self.__x,
                                      dtype=tf.float32)
            self.__outputs = outputs
            self.__states = states
```

I have this code nested in a larger class that just contains the remainder of the graph. To train it, I just call my "train" method over and over again. Which seems to work fine, the problem ends up being *prediction*.

So my question is two fold:

1. Why do I require some sort of variable sharing only after the *first* prediction but the first call doesn't fail? What do I need to fix this code so I can predict more than once without causing an error?
2. When is variable sharing useful, and why is Tensorflow creating new variables each time I run it? How can I prevent this (do I want to prevent it?)?

Thank you!

Comment: are you running inside a jupiter notebook? if you use the default graph, each time you run the cell it will add the variables again to the graph.

Comment: @fabrizioM I am not, I'm simply calling it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a print statement to that block of code.  I suspect it is being called multiple times. Or maybe you are creating multiple instances of the class in which each class should have its own scope name.

To answer your questions.

> Why do I require some sort of variable sharing only after the first
>   prediction but the first call doesn't fail? What do I need to fix this
>   code so I can predict more than once without causing an error?

No you don't.  That block of code creating the RNN is probably being accidentally called multiple times.

> When is variable sharing useful, and why is Tensorflow creating new
>   variables each time I run it? How can I prevent this (do I want to
>   prevent it?)?

It is useful in the following case where I have different input sources for part of my graph depending on whether is is training or predicting.

```
x_train, h_train = ops.sharpen_cell(x_train, h_train, 2, n_features, conv_size, n_convs, conv_activation, 'upsampler')
self.cost += tf.reduce_mean((x_train - y_train) ** 2)

level_scope.reuse_variables()

x_gen, h_gen = ops.sharpen_cell(x_gen, h_gen, 2, n_features, conv_size, n_convs, conv_activation, 'upsampler')
self.generator_outputs.append(tf.clip_by_value(x_gen, -1, 1))
```

In this example is reuses the variables for the generator which were trained with the trainer.  It is also useful if you want to unroll and RNN in a loop.  Such as in this case...

```
y = #initial value
state = #initial state
rnn = #some sort of RNN cell
with tf.variable_scope("rnn") as scope:
  for t in range(10):
    y, state = rnn(y, state)
    scope.reuse_variabled()
```

In this case it will reuse the rnn weights between time steps which is the desired behavior for an RNN.

Comment: Hey this worked great! I now have the same problem, except its occurring in the weight scope now. It seems to be centered around each time I call run it attempts to create a NEW variable. Would this be a case for reuse variables since it's trying to predict instead of train now?

Comment: I guess where I'm now confused is the difference between predicting and training, and why it would be attempting to recreate the graph with different weights/bias/etc when I call run on the predictor, rather than calling run on the optimizer. If you could add an explanation to that here I'd be happy to mark this the fully correct answer.

Comment: It should not be.  Put a print statement directly above where you call rnn.rnn.  I bet that block of code is being called twice.

Comment: indeed it is, it seem all the variable blocks are getting called twice in my code but I only ever call my graph creation function once. Session run is definitely triggering multiple calls. Does it help that I'm loading data from a checkpoint file?

Comment: You are the one calling that block twice not tensorflow.

Comment: Yes I agree. I am calling session.run twice to get two predictions using the session.run above. This shouldn't be generating new variables though, at least it doesn't seem. I'm definitely not call my create graph function twice.

Comment: I will mark this one closed and open a new question. This is just going to trail off into the comment blocks.